# Angularjs display images based on names in database

Tags: angularjs

I am attempting to display an image on a view.  I have a list of image names in the database and have the actual images stored in content/images.  All that is showing up when I loop through is the alternate name and I only get that once.  There should be 7 images or at the very least 7 alternate names being shown.

This is the code where I am attempting to show the images -

```
        <div class="row">
            <div ata-ng-repeat="route in vm.routes">
                <img data-ng-src="Content/images/{{route.department.imageNameLight}}.jpg" alt="test" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have looked a vm.routes and it does have the correct information. The image name is surrounded with quotes if that makes a difference?  Eventually I will have a maximum of two rows of six images either show the light version of the image or the dark depending on a status flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div ata-ng-repeat="route in vm.routes">
        <img data-ng-src="{{'Content/images/' + route.department.imageNameLight + '.jpg'}}" alt="test" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: After a whole lot of trial and error I finally got it to work with span, but how do I split after 6 elements have been shown?

Comment: Depending on what your layout needs are, one option would be to add something like `ng-style="{clear: $index % 6 == 0 ? 'left', 'none'}"` to wrap it to the next line, or another option is to create your data as an array of arrays and then use two nested `ng-repeats`.

Comment: The first option would assume that all your divs had `float: left`